# How to create an igraph with predefined id's of vertices?

Tags: r, igraph

I have the `id's` and `(x,y)`-coordinates of vertices. The edge list `el` is known too. I need to create a spatial graph.

**My attempt is below:**

```
library(igraph)
                      
id <- c(106, 110, 107, 102, 104, 103, 108, 111, 109, 101)
        
        cx <- c(270.2798, 156.4124, 270.2798, 100.0332, 156.4124, 100.0332, 156.4124, 156.4124, 156.4124, 100.0035)
                
cy <- c(401.2903, 420.2904, 470.4120, 401.2903, 348.2904, 348.2904, 470.4120, 401.2903, 436.8926, 470.1633)
        
el <- c(101,102, 102,103, 103,104, 104,111, 111,106,
                106,107, 107,108, 108,101, 108,109, 110,111)
        
dfw <- data.frame(id, cx, cy)
    
g2 <- make_empty_graph() %>%
add_vertices(nrow(dfw)) %>%
add_edges(el) # error is here
    
V(g2)$names <- dfw$id
    
mylayout2 <- as.matrix(cbind(dfw$cx, -dfw$cy))
    
plot(g2, layout=mylayout2,
               vertex.size = 10,
               vertex.label = V(g2)$name,  
               vertex.label.cex=.95, 
         )
```

**I have the error**

```
Error in add_edges(., el) : 
  At type_indexededgelist.c:272 : cannot add edges, Invalid vertex id
```

**Expected result is:**

[image]

**Question.** How to add the edges with the predefined `id's` of vertices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, to convert 101, 102, etc. to row numbers of `dfw` we may use `match`. Second, it should be

```
V(g2)$name <- dfw$id
```

instead of

```
V(g2)$names <- dfw$id
```

So, we have

```
g2 <- make_empty_graph() %>% add_vertices(nrow(dfw)) %>% add_edges(match(el, dfw$id))
V(g2)$name <- dfw$id
mylayout2 <- as.matrix(cbind(dfw$cx, -dfw$cy))
plot(g2, layout = mylayout2,
     vertex.size = 10,
     vertex.label = V(g2)$name,  
     vertex.label.cex = .95)
```

[image]